# Why this jQuery code works not more than 3 times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

While trying this following jQuery code (in Chrome. never tried in other browsers, but should show same result)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script>
  $(function(){
   $("#btn").on("click", function(){
    $("ul li:first").appendTo("ul li:last");
   });
  });
 </script>
 <style>
  .bold {
   font-weight: bold;
  }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <ul>
   <li>A</li>
   <li>B</li>
   <li>C</li>
  </ul>
  <input id="btn" type="button" value="SWAP"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

I click the button first time. As expected, the list changes to B,C,A from A,B,C, then clicked again and changed to C,A,B from B,C,A. But at third time I click the list becomes empty(only the button appears), but I expected to see the result A,B,C again. But why the list becomes empty?

Comment: Your code moves the `<li>` *inside* the last `<li>`. It should append to the `<ul>` instead.

Comment: If you take notice of the error in the console, I assume the issue is you are (eventually) trying to append an element to itself, which isn't valid DOM structure

Comment: use `insertAfter` instead of `appendTo`

Comment: @Pointy Thank you. I understand. at the last time things happen like, $("li").appendTo("li"); which causes it to disappear

Comment: @Taplar I looked at console from beginning to end and it showed nothing.

Comment: Run the code snippet on the site, and click the button three times.  It also shows up in the browser console.

Comment: I know it should show. But in my case, chrome is not showing it because after chrome update 77 it doesn't make error if you append an dom object to it. It will just hide it. I searched in Google

Answer (score 1):

you have to append in ul , But you are appending inside li
Change this

$("li:first").appendTo("ul:last");

Comment: I don't know if there are multiple ul on the page, but if so this whole question suffers from selectors being too global

Comment: Thanks for answering